# Trying to make a Tents and Trees game in C

Tags: c, algorithm, tree

i'm starting to learn C and i'm trying to make a tents and trees game, i'm at the part of making the level design with some matrices (4x4,5x5,6x6,7x7), for example, a number 8 represents a tree and a number 4 represents a tent and a number 0 is a blank space, however i'm trying to make the levels through random trees (8) positions to make the game different everytime you open it.

http://www.brainbashers.com/tentshelp.asp <- for more info

I need tips on how would you guys make the validation system for the trees, one tree has assigned one tent, but i'm getting way confused on how to make it work, I mean the trees  (8) numbers are created by a random position on the matrix, and all of the trees (8) numbers need a tent (4) number but the tents can't be never next to each other (vertically, horizontally, or diagonally) and they are always horizontally or vertically next to a tree and that's the part i'm getting confused setting up the tents for the generated trees.

Hope you guys understand what I mean, I'm really trying to learn so I just need tips please thank you in advance have a great day.

Comment: What code do you already have? If you don't have any actual code yet, maybe some pseudocode about how you might try to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some random thoughts that might help you arrange things:

1. In C / C++ a two-dimensional array is really a one-dimensional structure (a block of contiguous memory).  In C and C++ the 2-D array is stored in **row-major** form, meaning the we put the entire first row in memory, then the entire second row and so on.  So for example, if we had the following 
   2-D array

   ```
      0  1  2 <--- columns
   0  a  b  c
   1  d  e  f
   2  g  h  i
   ^
   +-- rows
   ```

it would be represented in memory (assuming we are using char as our underlying data-type) as:

```
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | 
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

This arrangement is useful, because we can easily convert between the index in the one-dimensional memory array and our conception of a 2-D array.  In the following equations, R, represents the maximum number of rows in our 2-D array (3 in this example) and, C, represents the maximum number of columns in our 2-D array (again 3 in this example).  On final note, we use a zero base for rows and columns; thus the element 'a' is in row 0, col 0, abbreviated as [0,0] in what follows..

So if we are interested in what is in [r,c] we need to generate an index, n, via;

```
    n = r * C + c
```

for example if we are interested in [1,1] we would calculate:

```
    n = 1 * 3 + 1 = 4
```

in other words, the element at [1,1] is located at fourth index (again remembering that arrays are zero-based).

We can also covert from an index, n, back into row-column notation by using;

```
    r = n / C  and c = n % C
```

for example the element at the sixth memory location (index = 5) would be

```
    r = 5 / 3  and c = 5 % 3  or [1,2]
```

2. Tree placement is fairly straight forward, in that if we are working with a n x n array, then we know our index run from [0, n$^2$-1], so we just generate random numbers in that range, just being sure to not use the same number twice.  Some psuedo-code might be for arranging t trees:

   ```
    // assume that our game board is in a data-structure called `world'
    len <-   n*n;                   // maximum number in our range
    trees <- t;                     // number of trees to place
    do
        ndx <- rand() % len         // generate random number in range [0,len-1]
        if ( world[ndx] == 0)       // picked an empty space
            world[ndx] = 8;         // plant a tree
            trees -= 1;             // decrement tree's remaining
    while (trees > 0);
   ```
3. Where to potentially put a tent is easy as well.  Thinking about the relationship between the 2-D array to the memory model, if a tree is located at a given index, ndx, the the list of possible tent locations is:

   ```
      L = ndx - 1;             // this is due left of the tree
      R = ndx + 1;             // this is due right of the tree
      B = ndx + C;             // this is below the tree
      A = ndx - C;             // this is above the tree
   ```

Of course, we must insure that we are not stepping off the world.  Personally, I would store these in an array rather than four variables.

4. Tent constraint really is just stating that there can't be a tent in any of the eight neighboring cells.  Consider the following diagram, where we have a tent in the cell marked by a T.  If the index of this cell is n, then the surrounding cells shows the indexs that we need to check.

   ```
           +---+---------+-----+----------+---+
           |   |         |     |          |   |
           +---+---------+-----+----------+---+
           |   | n-C - 1 | n-C | n-C + 1  |   |
           +---+---------+-----+----------+---+
           |   | n-1     | T   | n +1     |   |
           +---+---------+-----+----------+---+
           |   | n+C -1  | n+C | n+C +1   |   |
           +---+---------+-----+----------+---+
   ```
5. Lets put 3 and 4 together.  We first create a function `placeTents` that take an array of the indexes of where trees were placed.  This is a simple function, all it does it create an array of potential tree locations in the order {top, left, right, bottom} if any of those locations are out of bounds we set a negative one into the array.  Finally we attempt to generate a viable location for 
   the tent in the function placeTent(P); if placeTent fails we can't meet the constraint and from your problem description it is unclear on what you would like to do at this point, for this discussion I just indicated an exit of the program

   ```
   placeTents(trees):
       max <- R * C -1               // max index 
       for each tree in trees        
           if (tree - C) > 0 then P[0] = tree - C else P[0] = -1;
           if (tree - 1) > 0 then P[1] = tree - 1 else P[1] = -1;
           if (tree + 1) < max then P[2] = tree + 1 else P[2] = -1;
           if (tree + C) < max then P[3] = tree + C else P[3] = -1;
           if (!placeTent(P))
                exitError;
   ```

For placeTent, we need to check all eight-neighbors (which may not exist), and for simplicity we just place a tent in the first available location.  Again remember that placeTent accepts a list of the possible places to put a tent and then checks the viability of each location.  Again, we assume that the game board is in an array called `world`

```
     bool placeTent(P)  
         ret <- false;
         max <- R * C - 1;
         for each loc in P
             if loc == -1 continue;
             // calculate indexes we want to look at....
             trial[0] <- loc - Col - 1;
             trial[1] <- loc - Col;
                   .....
             trial[6] <- loc + Col;
             trial[7] <- loc + Col + 1;
             for each t in trial
                 if ((t < 0) || (t > max)) continue; // we fell of the world.....splat!
                 if (world[t] == 0)
                     world[t] = 4;
                     return true;
         return false;                               // failed to find a place to pitch our tent
```

Finally, the real challenge would be to find a viable location for tents, for this I'd thing about recursion so that when I fail to find a viable location we can unwind the locations and try a different path.

And seeing the length that this spun into .... sorry, probably rambled way, way too much....I'll leave the recursion part for later.

edit / addition:

one other thing I forgot to mention, the above is very deterministic, i.e. we allows attempt to place a tent above a tree and then move counter-clockwise.  At some point people will figure this out, so you probably want to randomize the order of places to check (i.e. create a permutation on the P array for every tree.)

Comment: Wow dude thank you! that really helped me out! I finished it haha thanks!